# How to print out to "log" without affecting anything else (lua print equiv)

Tags: debugging, logging

lua's `print` is very effective for my debugging purposes but I can't easily use it in TeX because of all the macro expansion issues.

All it does is print the text to the window (console window or whatever; I use WinEdt) but doesn't effect output in any way.

I've tried `\the`, `\showthe`, and `\message` and none seem to work well.

Is there any easy way that will allow me to print macro and register values for debugging purposes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to display macro and register contents in the terminal and the log, then the two primitives you want are `\show` and `\showthe`. Macros are displayed using `\show`:

```
\def\foo{some tokens}
\show\foo
```

leads to

```
> \foo=macro:
->some tokens.
l.5 \show\foo
```

for example. If you try `\show` with a register it's not so helpful, with for example

```
\newcount\foo
\show\foo
```

giving

```
> \foo=\count201.
l.5 \show\foo
```

This is where `\showthe` comes in, as with

```
\newcount\foo
\foo 10\relax
\showthe\foo
```

you get

```
> 10.
l.7     \showthe\foo
```

The same applies to other register types (toks, dimens, skips).

`\message` writes the terminal and the log without interrupting the run and with expansion. So

```
\def\foo{bar}
\message{Hello world \foo}
```

writes

```
Hello world bar
```

to the terminal bu tdoes not stop the run. If you want to write the content of a register *via* `\message` you need to include `\the`:

```
\newtoks\foo
\foo{bar}
\message{Hello world \the\foo}
```

once again outputs

```
Hello world bar
```

Another useful primitive in this context is e-TeX's `\showtokens`, which can be used to show arbitrary tokens in the terminal and so is useful for constructing 'interactive' messages without issuing an error. The latter is carried out using `\errmessage`, which takes a little setting up if you want 'pretty printing' (see for example how this is handled by LaTeX2e in `latex.ltx`).

Comment: Ok, it seems one has to use `\the` in `\message` for counters and not `\showthe`.

Comment: The argument of `\message` is an expansion context: material is expanded but not executed. The `\showthe` primitive is not expandable (none of the write-like operations are), and so if you use `\showthe` inside `\message` you will get `\showthe` printed as part of the terminal output!

Comment: There is also `\typeout{}` that prints console messages